# How does $A^{123}A^{*}_{123}$ look when expanded?

Tags: tensors

tensors are a new subject for me.  I am trying to expand $A^{123}A^{*}_{123}$

Does it look something like the following?

$A^{111}A^{*}_{111}+2(A^{112}A^{*}_{112})+2(A^{122}A^{*}_{122})+A^{222}A^{*}_{222}$

Comment: There's a lot of context missing from this question.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews:  OK, I'll try to add more description with future questions!  Thnks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might imagine that the superscript and subscript "$123$" should have been "$ijk$", with the Einstein summation convention in force; one might imagine that the third-rank tensor $A$ is defined on a two-dimensional vector space; and one might imagine that this tensor $A$ is completely symmetric among all three of its indices. With all this imagination, the proposed expansion is no longer nonsense but merely wrong in that the coefficients $2$ should both be $3$. I can't think of any other understanding of the question that makes the proposed expansion only slightly wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it represents a vector space... the question came from a physics professor.  Yes, thank you Andreas Blass.  Einstein summation is right.  I will use $"ijk"$ from now on.  I really appreciate your help!!!